# reading and querying a txt/log file using c#

Tags: c#

i have created a log file example.txt that records events as

```
Button1 Click event happen ID=xyz DT:3/1/2015 9:27:32 AM
Button2 Click event happen ID=xyz DT:3/1/2015 9:28:32 AM
Button1 Click event happen ID=xyz DT:3/1/2015 9:29:32 AM
Button2 Click event happen ID=xyz DT:3/1/2015 9:30:32 AM
```

i can read those file but i will get everything written in the log file.\
i have used the following code

```
    try
    {
      using(FileStream fileStream = new FileStream("c://temp1/example_logfile.txt",FileMode.Open,FileAccess.Read,FileShare.ReadWrite))
       {
            using(StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(fileStream))
            {
                this.txt.Text = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
     }
```

I want to read just the Button1 click event. how do you do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about a solution with `StreamReader.ReadLine()` combined with `String.Contains()`

```
   String line;

   while (!streamReader.EndOfStream)  // <= Check for end of file
   {
     line = streamReader.ReadLine(); // <=Get a single line
     if (line.Contains("Button1"))  // <= Check for condition ; line contains 'Button1'
        {
          this.txt.Text += line + "\n"; // <== Append text  with a newline 
        } 
     }
```

Answer (score 4):

Use [`File.ReadLines`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503(v=vs.110).aspx) and a bit of LINQ to get only the lines you're interested in:

```
var results = File.ReadLines(filePath).Where(x => x.StartsWith("Button1 Click"));
```

Now you've got a collection of strings representing the matching lines. If you want to display them in a single `TextBox`, you can flatten the list back out to a single string:

```
this.txt.Text = String.Join(", ", results);
```

Or modify the LINQ statement to get, say, the first match only: *(assuming at least one match)*

```
this.txt.Text = File.ReadLines(filePath).First(x => x.StartsWith("Button1 Click"));
```

Comment: i tried but it gave me thisSystem.Linq.Enumerable+WhereEnumerableIterator`1[System.String]

Comment: Because you're trying to shove a list into a single TextBox. You have two "Button1 Click" records - how do you intend to place them in a single TextBox?